# How to pull data from SQL Server to list them in Combo Box VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I would like to know how is your way on pulling data from SQL Server to a combobox. I've been trying various solutions but I couldn't make them work.

I've been using this code in my Login form

```
Private Sub SQLConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SQLConnect.Click
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    connetionString = "Server=" + SQLServer.Text + ";Database=PriceOrders;User Id=" + SQLUser.Text + ";Password=" + SQLPwd.Text + ";"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        MsgBox("Successfully connected!", vbInformation)
        cnn.Close()
        Hide()
        frmMain.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Invalid Login! Please try again.", vbExclamation)
        SQLUser.Text = ""
        SQLPwd.Text = ""
        SQLUser.Focus()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Will this connection be imported to other form? Because I have my combo box on the other form from this login form.

Thanks guys.

Comment: You cannot use the connection to other forms because you declared your `SQLConnection` inside your sub. You can declare a `Global` variable for you to be able to use the connection in your other forms.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I added them as globalvariables.

Comment: Don't use the one connection on multiple forms.  You can put your connection string somewhere common and then create a connection object using that connection string where and when you need to.  ADO.NET connections are intended to be created and destroyed regularly.